# iframe Placeholder Image

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I'm trying to make an iframe that will display a static image, then load a webpage within the iframe when a user clicks on the placeholder image. It's for a virtual tour, so the image will display the instructions, then view the virtual tour (link) when clicked. I know how to change iframe links using buttons, but for this particular application a clickable image is preferred. I'm fairly inexperienced, so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just put the iframe in a div, and put the background on the div, then make the iframe transparent, but not its contents.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>

    <style type="text/css">
      .iframeframe { background-image: url("whatever.lol"); margin: 0; padding: 0; display: inline-block; }
      iframe       { width: 600px; height: 400px; }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="iframeframe">
      <iframe src="whatever.lol"></iframe>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```